# AngularJS foreach not able to find function within same Service

Tags: arrays, angularjs, typescript

need some help, for the life of me I can't get this to work. I'm trying to loop through an array which is within a config value and then trigger another function within the service I created, but I get an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerToken' of undefined
```

Is there not a better way to do this it feels very clunky?

CampaignService.ts

```
import { ServerConfig } from "../core/ServerConfig";

declare var config: ServerConfig;

export class CampaignService {
  static $inject = ["localStorageService"];

  constructor(
    public localStorageService: angular.local.storage.ILocalStorageService
  ) {

  }             

  launchCampaign(campaignToken: string) {
    if (campaignToken) {
      config.campaigns.forEach(function (data) {
        if (campaignToken == data.title) {
          if (data.enabled) {
            this.registerToken(campaignToken);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };

  registerToken(campaignToken: string) {

  }    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I found this to be the best shorthand might be wrong, comments welcome

```
import { ServerConfig } from "../core/ServerConfig";

declare var config: ServerConfig;

export class CampaignService {
  static $inject = ["localStorageService"];

  constructor(
    public localStorageService: angular.local.storage.ILocalStorageService
  ) {

  }             

  launchCampaign(campaignToken: string) {
    if (campaignToken) {
       (config.campaigns.find(function (obj) { return obj.title === campaignToken; })) ? this.registerToken(campaignToken) : void (0);
    }
  };

  registerToken(campaignToken: string) {

  }    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an **[`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)** which have the context,

```
 config.campaigns.forEach((data) => {
        if (campaignToken == data.title) {
          if (data.enabled) {
            this.registerToken(campaignToken);
          }
        }
 });
```

Comment: Awesome thanks @sajeetharan small things that had me for hours. I see this also seems to work

`var obj = config.campaigns.find(function (obj) { return obj.title === campaignToken; });`

Comment: Great if that helped

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it will be passing outer "this" to the forEach function, then the foreach have "this" context defined.

Something like:

```
config.campaigns.forEach(function (data) {
    if (campaignToken == data.title) {
      if (data.enabled) {
        this.registerToken(campaignToken);
      }
    }
}, this);
```

You can refer the documentation of foreach [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).